# Почему не запускается приложение KIVY?

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

При запуске приложения, запускается на 3-5 сек и пропадает, почему? Не могу понять что за ошибка?

```
03-04 14:50:18.130 29431 29463 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
03-04 14:50:18.130 29431 29463 I python  : AND: Ran string
03-04 14:50:18.130 29431 29463 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
03-04 14:50:18.215 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_22-03-04_4.txt
03-04 14:50:18.215 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
03-04 14:50:18.215 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
03-04 14:50:18.215 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.9 (default, Mar  4 2022, 11:06:35)
03-04 14:50:18.215 29431 29463 I python  : [Clang 8.0.2 (************************************************ 40173bab62ec7462
03-04 14:50:18.215 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
03-04 14:50:18.794 29431 29431 W SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:240742): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/binascii.cpython-38.so" dev="dm-10" ino=142036 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file app=org.test.myapp
03-04 14:50:18.804 29431 29431 W SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:240743): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/_contextvars.cpython-38.so" dev="dm-10" ino=603101 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file app=org.test.myapp
03-04 14:50:18.824 29431 29431 W SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:240745): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/_event.so" dev="dm-10" ino=220516 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file app=org.test.myapp
03-04 14:50:18.837 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
03-04 14:50:19.019 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
03-04 14:50:19.054 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
03-04 14:50:19.069 29431 29463 E libEGL  : validate_display:87 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
03-04 14:50:19.070 29431 29463 V SDL     : setOrientation() orientation=-1 width=800 height=600 resizable=true hint=
03-04 14:50:19.073 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
03-04 14:50:19.074 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
03-04 14:50:19.074 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 V@0502.0 (GIT@e1ac91e, I2b3b5fbd00, 1605635143) (Date:11/17/20)'>
03-04 14:50:19.074 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Qualcomm'>
03-04 14:50:19.074 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Adreno (TM) 618'>
03-04 14:50:19.074 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
03-04 14:50:19.075 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
03-04 14:50:19.075 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
03-04 14:50:19.087 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
03-04 14:50:19.088 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
03-04 14:50:19.232 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
03-04 14:50:19.296 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
03-04 14:50:19.372 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [Camera      ] Provider: android
03-04 14:50:19.437 29431 29463 V PythonActivity: addPermissionsCallback(): Added callback for onRequestPermissionsResult
03-04 14:50:19.455 29431 29431 V PythonActivity: onPause()
03-04 14:50:19.455 29431 29431 V SDL     : onPause()
03-04 14:50:19.456 29431 29431 V SDL     : nativePause()
03-04 14:50:19.458 29431 29463 W Activity: Can request only one set of permissions at a time
03-04 14:50:19.458 29431 29463 V PythonActivity: onRequestPermissionsResult()
03-04 14:50:19.458 29431 29463 V PythonActivity: onRequestPermissionsResult passed to callback
03-04 14:50:19.495 29431 29463 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
03-04 14:50:19.495 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
03-04 14:50:19.516 29431 29431 V SDL     : onWindowFocusChanged(): false
03-04 14:50:19.527 19469 19481 W ssioncontrolle: Reducing the number of considered missed Gc histogram windows from 103 to 100
03-04 14:50:19.548 19469 19469 D ViewRootImpl[GrantPermissionsActivity]: msg2 update new insets InsetsState: {mDisplayFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400), mSources= { InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_STATUS_BAR, mFrame=[0,0][1080,77], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,0][1080,77], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_LEFT_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,0][0,0], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_RIGHT_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,0][0,0], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_TAPPABLE_ELEMENT, mFrame=[0,0][1080,77], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_LEFT_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,0][-2147483648,2400], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,0][1080,76], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_RIGHT_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[2147483647,0][1080,2400], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_BOTTOM_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,2147483647][1080,2400], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_IME, mFrame=[0,0][0,0], mVisible=false} }
03-04 14:50:19.559 29431 29431 D ViewRootImpl[PythonActivity]: msg2 update new insets InsetsState: {mDisplayFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400), mSources= { InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_STATUS_BAR, mFrame=[0,0][1080,77], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,0][1080,77], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_LEFT_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,0][0,0], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_RIGHT_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,0][0,0], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_TAPPABLE_ELEMENT, mFrame=[0,0][1080,77], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_LEFT_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,0][-2147483648,2400], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,0][1080,76], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_RIGHT_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[2147483647,0][1080,2400], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_BOTTOM_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,2147483647][1080,2400], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_IME, mFrame=[0,0][0,0], mVisible=false} }
03-04 14:50:19.562  1701  1896 I ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.google.android.permissioncontroller/com.android.permissioncontroller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity: +110ms
03-04 14:50:19.580 19469 19469 E GrantPermissionsViewModel: None of [android.permission.CAMERA] in {android.permission-group.STORAGE=[android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION]}
03-04 14:50:19.615 29431 29431 V PythonActivity: onRequestPermissionsResult()
03-04 14:50:19.615 29431 29431 V PythonActivity: onRequestPermissionsResult passed to callback
03-04 14:50:19.617 29431 29431 V PythonActivity: onResume()
03-04 14:50:19.617 29431 29431 V SDL     : onResume()
03-04 14:50:19.645 29431 29431 D ViewRootImpl[PythonActivity]: msg2 update new insets InsetsState: {mDisplayFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400), mSources= { InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_STATUS_BAR, mFrame=[0,0][1080,77], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,0][1080,77], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_LEFT_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,0][0,0], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_RIGHT_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,0][0,0], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_TAPPABLE_ELEMENT, mFrame=[0,0][1080,77], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_LEFT_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,0][-2147483648,2400], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,0][1080,76], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_RIGHT_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[2147483647,0][1080,2400], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_BOTTOM_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,2147483647][1080,2400], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_IME, mFrame=[0,0][0,0], mVisible=false} }
03-04 14:50:19.646 29431 29431 V SDL     : onWindowFocusChanged(): true
03-04 14:50:19.646 29431 29431 V SDL     : nativeResume()
03-04 14:50:19.668 17802 17802 I GoogleInputMethodService: GoogleInputMethodService.onFinishInput():3293
03-04 14:50:19.669 17802 17802 I GoogleInputMethodService: GoogleInputMethodService.onStartInput():1981
03-04 14:50:19.670 17802 17802 I DeviceUnlockedTag: DeviceUnlockedTag.notifyDeviceLockStatusChanged():79 Notify device unlocked.
03-04 14:50:21.841 29431 29463 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
03-04 14:50:21.842 29431 29463 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
03-04 14:50:21.842 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
03-04 14:50:21.843 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
03-04 14:50:21.844 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
03-04 14:50:21.844 29431 29463 I python  :  socket.gaierror: [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname
03-04 14:50:21.844 29431 29463 I python  :
03-04 14:50:21.845 29431 29463 I python  :  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
03-04 14:50:21.846 29431 29463 I python  :
03-04 14:50:21.846 29431 29463 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
03-04 14:50:21.846 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
03-04 14:50:21.847 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
03-04 14:50:21.848 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/connection.py", line 239, in request
03-04 14:50:21.848 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/http/client.py", line 1252, in request
03-04 14:50:21.849 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
03-04 14:50:21.849 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
03-04 14:50:21.850 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/http/client.py", line 1007, in _send_output
03-04 14:50:21.850 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/http/client.py", line 947, in send
03-04 14:50:21.851 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
03-04 14:50:21.851 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
03-04 14:50:21.852 29431 29463 I python  :  urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xbc62c640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname
03-04 14:50:21.852 29431 29463 I python  :
03-04 14:50:21.852 29431 29463 I python  :  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
03-04 14:50:21.853 29431 29463 I python  :
03-04 14:50:21.853 29431 29463 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
03-04 14:50:21.853 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
03-04 14:50:21.854 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
03-04 14:50:21.854 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
03-04 14:50:21.856 29431 29463 I python  :  urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='code-factory.site', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/notice/upakovka (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xbc62c640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname'))
03-04 14:50:21.856 29431 29463 I python  :
03-04 14:50:21.856 29431 29463 I python  :  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
03-04 14:50:21.857 29431 29463 I python  :
03-04 14:50:21.857 29431 29463 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
03-04 14:50:21.857 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 239, in <module>
03-04 14:50:21.857 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/app.py", line 950, in run
03-04 14:50:21.857 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
03-04 14:50:21.857 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/base.py", line 347, in mainloop
03-04 14:50:21.858 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/base.py", line 387, in idle
03-04 14:50:21.858 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/clock.py", line 733, in tick
03-04 14:50:21.858 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/clock.py", line 776, in post_idle
03-04 14:50:21.858 29431 29463 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 616, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
03-04 14:50:21.858 29431 29463 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 649, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
03-04 14:50:21.860 29431 29463 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 645, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
03-04 14:50:21.861 29431 29463 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 218, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
03-04 14:50:21.861 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 208, in get_notice
03-04 14:50:21.861 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
03-04 14:50:21.861 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
03-04 14:50:21.861 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
03-04 14:50:21.862 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/requests/sessions.py", line 645, in send
03-04 14:50:21.862 29431 29463 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/requests/adapters.py", line 519, in send
03-04 14:50:21.862 29431 29463 I python  :  requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='code-factory.site', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/notice/upakovka (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xbc62c640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname'))
03-04 14:50:21.862 29431 29463 I python  : Python for android ended.
03-04 14:50:22.065 17802 17802 I GoogleInputMethodService: GoogleInputMethodService.onFinishInput():3293
03-04 14:50:22.066 17802 17802 I GoogleInputMethodService: GoogleInputMethodService.onStartInput():1981
03-04 14:50:22.067 17802 17802 I DeviceUnlockedTag: DeviceUnlockedTag.notifyDeviceLockStatusChanged():79 Notify device unlocked.
```

Команды:

```
!pip install cython==0.29.19

!sudo apt-get install -y \
    python3-pip \
    build-essential \
    git \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    ffmpeg \
    libsdl2-dev \
    libsdl2-image-dev \
    libsdl2-mixer-dev \
    libsdl2-ttf-dev \
    libportmidi-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    zlib1g-dev

!sudo apt-get install -y \
    libgstreamer1.0 \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good

!sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev libffi6

!sudo apt-get install libffi-dev

!sudo pip3 install kivy
!sudo pip3 install kivymd
!sudo pip install zbarcam
!sudo pip install urllib3
!sudo pip install requests
!sudo pip install chardet
!sudo pip install idna
!sudo pip install opencv-python
!sudo pip install Pillow
!sudo pip install kivy-garden.xcamera
!sudo pip install pyzbar
!sudo pip install python-android
```

!buildozer init и !buildozer -v android debug

Сам код:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from requests import get, post


ENDPOINT = 'https://code-factory.site/'

Window.size = (560, 780)
Window.clearcolor = (0, 0.17, 0.55, 1)


notice_list = []
try:
    with open('f.txt', 'r') as f:
        file = f.readlines()
        department = file[0].replace('\n', '')
        otk = file[1].replace('\n', '')
except:
    department = None
    otk = None

buttons = """
        Button:
            id: back
            text: 'ВОЗВРАЩЕНИЕ ЗАКАЗА НА ДОРАБОТКУ'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.server('back', False)
""" if otk == "otk" or otk == None else ''

Builder.load_string(f"""
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 5, 5
        spacing: 5

        Button:
            text: 'УВЕДОМЛЕНИЯ'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.clear()
            Image:
                source: 'bell-ring.png'
                id: bell
                opacity: 0
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 30, 30
                center_x: 330
                center_y: 450
        Button:
            text: 'ЗАКАЗЫ В РАБОТЕ'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'foto'
        Button:
            text: 'СКАНИРОВАНИЕ QR'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'scan'

<AllScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'KM'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.save('km')
        Button:
            text: 'KMД'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.save('kmd')
        Button:
            text: 'ТМЦ'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.save('tmc')
        Button:
            text: 'ЗАГОТОВКА'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.save('zagatovka')
        Button:
            text: 'СБОРКА'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.save('sborka')
        Button:
            text: 'СВАРКА'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.save('svarka')
        Button:
            text: 'УПАКОВКА'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.save('upakovka')

<All2Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'Производство'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.save('not_otk')
        Button:
            text: 'ОТК'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.save('otk')

<FotoScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            background_color: (0, 0.17, 0.55, 1)
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
            Image:
                source: 'demo_01.png'
                size: self.parent.size

<ScanScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
    #:import ZBarCam kivy_garden.zbarcam.ZBarCam
        id: box
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 5, 5
        spacing: 5
        ZBarCam:
            id: qrcodecam
        Label:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.texture_size[0], 50
            id: qr_text
            text: ' '

        Button:
            text: 'РАБОТА НАЧАТА'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.server('start', True)
        Button:
            text: 'РАБОТА ПРИОСТАНОВЛЕНА/ВОЗОБНОВЛЕНА'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.server('stop', True)
        Button:
            text: 'ОБРАТНО В МЕНЮ'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        Button:
            text: 'ОТСКАНИРОВАТЬ'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.get_qr()
        Button:
            text: 'РАБОТА ЗАКОНЧЕНА'
            background_color: (0, 0.12, 0.52, 1)
            on_press: root.server('end', True)
""" + buttons)


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def clear(self):
        global notice_list
        notice_list.clear()


class AllScreen(Screen):
    def save(self, select):
        global department
        department = select

        with open('f.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(f'{department}\n')

        App.get_running_app().root.current = 'select_otk'

class All2Screen(Screen):
    def save(self, select):
        global otk
        otk = select

        with open('f.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(f'{otk}\n')

        if otk != 'otk':
            scan_screen = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('scan')

            scan_screen.ids['box'].remove_widget(scan_screen.ids['back'])

        App.get_running_app().root.current = 'menu'

class FotoScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScanScreen(Screen):
    def server(self, command, check_otk):
        r = get(f'https://code-factory.site/api/give_csrf')
        csrf = r.text.split('=')[-1][1:-2]
        cookies = r.cookies.get_dict()

        add = ''
        if check_otk and otk == 'otk':
            add = '_otk'

        post(f'https://code-factory.site/api/{command}{add}/{department}',
             data = {'id': self.ids['qr_text'].text.split('\n')[0], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf},
             cookies = cookies)

        self.ids['qr_text'].text = ''

    def get_qr(self):
        qr = ''.join([symbol.data.decode('utf-8') for symbol in self.ids['qrcodecam'].symbols])

        self.ids['qr_text'].text = qr


def get_notice(_):
    for i in get(f'https://code-factory.site/api/notice/{department}').text.split(','):
        if i != '':
            notice_list.append(i)

    if len(notice_list) > 0:
        App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('menu').ids['bell'].opacity = 1
    else:
        App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('menu').ids['bell'].opacity = 0


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()

        sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(ScanScreen(name='scan'))
        sm.add_widget(FotoScreen(name='foto'))
        sm.add_widget(AllScreen(name='all'))
        sm.add_widget(All2Screen(name='select_otk'))

        if department == None or department == 'None' or otk == None or otk == 'None':
            sm.current = 'all'
        else:
            sm.current = 'menu'

        return sm


if __name__=='__main__':
    Clock.schedule_interval(get_notice, 3)

    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Вот тут наверное все и написано, имя хоста не ресолвится `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='code-factory.site', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/notice/upakovka (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xbc62c640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname'))`

Comment: А как обойти эту ошибку?

Comment: У вас какая-то банальная проблема с DNS, сайт с телефона открывается?

Comment: Что необходимо сделать с DNS?

Comment: Для начала проверить, что ваш ENDPOINT в браузере телефона открывается. Если да, то идти смотреть манифест приложения на предмет доступа к интернету.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Победа! Нужно было добавить разрешение на доступ к камере и интернету в buildozer.spec